# Visual studio asp.net code behind file not showing errors

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application in which I am suddenly facing an issue. I have a webpage which contains many controls, one of the control is JQuery color picker. Now, I am upgrading my system with telerik controls. As part of this process, I replaced textbox(txtcolor) with radcolorpicker with a different id(colorPicker). Suddenly, my code behind file is not throwing any errors like 'unable to find txtColor'. It is running successfully without build errors. But, when I open the page, system is throwing runtime exception(txtColor not found) which is correct.

I tried to change other controls with asp.net controls, still the problem persists. So, I dont think it is anything to do with telerik.

Could you please let me know how can fix this issue??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to directly reference controls in your code, the references reside in the designer.cs file, which can get out of sorts; if you manually edit, it should be fine...

If not, could you post a code sample of what isn't working?

Thanks.